# when i created a maven project for the first time it shows me error in my pom.xml file the error is :

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.pranik</groupId>
<artifactId>ServletJspDemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>A custom project</name>
<url>http://www.haoxuer.com</url>

 

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

**error: Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer**

the error is in the first line and i cant understand what it is?

Comment: Please add all output. The way you have called Maven? Which Maven you are using? Have you called from plain command Line? Which JDK you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Maven is unable to load plugins may be due to lower ver of Web Module.

Try adding plugins in pom.xml and update Maven project.
Hope it works.

```
<build>
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
  </build>
```